# See IP addresses that access my computer

Tags: samba, log, shared-folders

How can I **see time/date/ip address** of the computers that **accessed my computer**, and is it possible to see if they accessed **any (and which) files** that I share using **samba**?

Is there any **samba log file**?

Just to add: directories are shared **without** username/password.

Comment: Not 100% sure but take a look at the configuration file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` this should have an entry for log file e.g. `log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log` take a look there.

Comment: I think I found the answer. The log files can be found in:
`/var/log/samba/`

where files are named as `log.[COMPUTER_NAME]`

With all time/date file access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can enable samba user activity logging. Find the instructions in the following page.
http://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but it might help though.

`iftop -i <interface>` shows all the network traffic on the corresponding interface in real time.

Comment: OK for real time. I want to know the history of the accesses to my shared folders (if it's by default samba installation). I guess there are extensions/programs which could cover this topic.